# Concatenate dfs together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a list of lists of dfs in the form like this

```
ls = [[df1, df2, df3], [df4, df5, df6], [df7, df8, df9]]
```

I want to somehow concatenate along columns so that the resulting list is like this

```
ls = [pd.concat([df1, df4, df7], axis=0),
      pd.concat([df2, df5, df8], axis=0),
      pd.concat([df3, df6, df9], axis=0)]
```

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this. I guess a naive way could be to use 2 for loops and iterate over columns, making a new list, and the using `pd.concat` to make one? But is there a better way then that using maybe numpy arrays or some function I do not know about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](/q/6473679/4518341)

Comment: And yes thanks I think that is what I want, now that I reflect on it I am just doing a matrix transposition I just wasn't thinking of it that way.

Comment: tldr; `out = [pd.concat(x) for x in zip(*ls)]`